# What protection scheme for my passwords?

Tags: delphi, encryption, passwords, store

I'm developing a software (for personal use) with Delphi.

But I have a problem, this is it :

-> There's a main password to access a some other password file.

-> When storing these password, i use as key the main password. I think, it's ok.
-> But how protect the main password, and allow modification of it  ???

If I use a constant key (so stored in the code, in binary), It can be disassembled !

So, I'm crazy or there's a way to make this possible : Protect main password and derived passwords.

(Main password (choosen by user) -> use it as key when encrypting user data (other password and usernames related).

Thank you for your helps.
Excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 19):

i'd like to suggest turning the problem on its head. Your Windows account is already protected with a password. The Win32 API provides a mechanism where you can have Windows encrypt data with your Windows password.

This means that your data is as secure as your Windows password; and you don't need to memorize a second password.

The Windows function [`CredWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CredRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allow storing and saving of credentials; of which i just happen to have a handy wrapper function already for storing credentials:

```
function CredWriteGenericCredentials(const Target, Username, Password: WideString): Boolean;
var
    PersistType: DWORD;
    Credentials: CREDENTIALW;
    hr: DWORD;
    s: string;
begin
    if not CredGetMaxPersistType(CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, {var}PersistType) then
    begin
        Result := False;
        Exit;
    end;

    ZeroMemory(@Credentials, SizeOf(Credentials));
    Credentials.TargetName := PWideChar(Target); //cannot be longer than CRED_MAX_GENERIC_TARGET_NAME_LENGTH (32767) characters. Recommended format "Company_Target"
    Credentials.Type_ := CRED_TYPE_GENERIC;
    Credentials.UserName := PWideChar(Username);
    Credentials.Persist := PersistType; //CRED_PERSIST_ENTERPRISE; //local machine and roaming
    Credentials.CredentialBlob := PByte(Password);
    Credentials.CredentialBlobSize := 2*(Length(Password)); //By convention no trailing null. Cannot be longer than CRED_MAX_CREDENTIAL_BLOB_SIZE (512) bytes
    Credentials.UserName := PWideChar(Username);
    Result := CredWriteW(Credentials, 0);

    if not Result then
    begin
        hr := GetLastError;
        case hr of
        CredUI.ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION: s := 'The logon session does not exist or there is no credential set associated with this logon session. Network logon sessions do not have an associated credential set. (ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION)';
        CredUI.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER: s := 'Certain fields cannot be changed in an existing credential. This error is returned if a field does not match the value in a protected field of the existing credential. (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)';
        CredUI.ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS: s := 'A value that is not valid was specified for the Flags parameter. (ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS)';
        ERROR_BAD_USERNAME: s := 'The UserName member of the passed in Credential structure is not valid. For a description of valid user name syntax, see the definition of that member. (ERROR_BAD_USERNAME)';
        ERROR_NOT_FOUND: s := 'CRED_PRESERVE_CREDENTIAL_BLOB was specified and there is no existing credential by the same TargetName and Type. (ERROR_NOT_FOUND)';
//      SCARD_E_NO_READERS_AVAILABLE: raise Exception.Create('The CRED_TYPE_CERTIFICATE credential being written requires the smart card reader to be available. (SCARD_E_NO_READERS_AVAILABLE)');
//      SCARD_E_NO_SMARTCARD: raise Exception.Create('A CRED_TYPE_CERTIFICATE credential being written requires the smart card to be inserted. (SCARD_E_NO_SMARTCARD)');
//      SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD: raise Exception.Create('A CRED_TYPE_CERTIFICATE credential being written requires the smart card to be inserted. (SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD)');
//      SCARD_W_WRONG_CHV: raise Exception.Create('The wrong PIN was supplied for the CRED_TYPE_CERTIFICATE credential being written. (SCARD_W_WRONG_CHV)');
        else
            s := SysErrorMessage(hr)+' (0x'+IntToHex(hr, 8)+')';
        end;
        OutputDebugString(PChar(s));
    end;
end;
```

And a wrapper function to read credentials:

```
function CredReadGenericCredentials(const Target: WideString; var Username, Password: WideString): Boolean;
var
    Credential: PCREDENTIALW;
begin
    Credential := nil;
    if CredReadW(Target, CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, 0, Credential) then
    begin
        try
            username := Credential.UserName;
            password := WideCharToWideString(PWideChar(Credential.CredentialBlob), Credential.CredentialBlobSize); //By convention blobs that contain strings do not have a trailing NULL.
        finally
            CredFree(Credential);
        end;

        Result := True;
    end
    else
        Result := False;
end;
```

It should be noted that `CredRead` and `CredWrite` are themselves functions that turn around and use [`CryptProtectData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CryptUnprotectData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

These functions let you take some arbitrary *blob*, and encrypt it with the user account's password<sup>1</sup>, and then hand you back the encrypted *blob*. You can then store that *blob* wherever you like (e.g. registry or file).

Later you can have the blob decrypted, and can only be decrypted by the user who originally encrypted it.

This lets you have your dream of forcing you to deal with another password, but uses Windows to protect it.

```
"MyPassword04" --> CryptProtectData() --> "TXlQYXNzd29yZDA0"
```

You can store your encrypted password anywhere you like. Then later:

```
"TXlQYXNzd29yZDA0" --> CryptUnprotectData() --> "MyPassword04"
```

The suggestion i'm making is the ability to abandon passwords; leveraging the security of your own account.

Just a suggestion; you're free to consider, and reject, it.

---

**Update**

Additional helper functions.

Convert a `PWideChar` to a `WideString` (if there's a built-in (Delphi 5) function for it, i've never found it):

```
function WideCharToWideString(Source: PWideChar; SourceLen: Integer): WideString;
begin
    if (SourceLen <= 0) then
    begin
        Result := '';
        Exit;
    end;

    SetLength(Result, SourceLen div 2);
    Move(Source^, Result[1], SourceLen);
end;
```

There are different "scopes" that you'r allowed to store credentails in:

- `CRED_PERSIST_NONE`: No credential can be stored. This value will be returned if the credential type is not supported or has been disabled by policy.
- `CRED_PERSIST_SESSION`: Only a session-specific credential can be stored.
- `CRED_PERSIST_LOCAL_MACHINE`: Session-specific and computer-specific credentials can be stored.
   **Windows XP**:  This credential cannot be stored for sessions in which the profile is not loaded.
- `CRED_PERSIST_ENTERPRISE`: Any credential can be stored.
   **Windows XP**:  This credential cannot be stored for sessions in which the profile is not loaded.

This function returns the highest supported persistence type for a given credential type (e.g. "generic" credentails). It's needed when you call `CredWrite` that you don't try to persist it in a location that isn't supported (i.e. in the domain when there is no domain):

```
type
    TCredGetSessionTypes = function(MaximumPersistCount: DWORD; MaximumPersist: LPDWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
function CredGetMaxPersistType(CredType: DWORD; var MaxCredPersistType: DWORD): Boolean;
const
    CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM = 5;
var
    _CredGetSessionTypes: TCredGetSessionTypes;
    MaximumPersist: array[0..CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM-1] of DWORD;
begin
    _CredGetSessionTypes := GetProcedureAddress(advapi32, 'CredGetSessionTypes');

    if Assigned(_CredGetSessionTypes) then
    begin
        Result := _CredGetSessionTypes(CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM, PDWORD(@MaximumPersist[0]));
        if Result then
            MaxCredPersistType := MaximumPersist[CredType]
        else
            MaxCredPersistType := 0;
    end
    else
    begin
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION);
        Result := False;
        MaxCredPersistType := 0;
    end;
end;
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: Good, but it's a little bit difficult for me (yes :() and I don't like to be dependent of Windows security and User. Thank you !

Comment: I think this is great.  Even if you don't want to be dependant on windows security when you aren't on windows, this is a slam dunk easy choice for when you're on windows, in Delphi.  You could re-encrypt your clear text "password db" using some other strong encryption when storing it on a web site, for instance, but this would be great for regular daily storage.

Comment: @Ian Boyd.  What happens if a file encrypted with an old Windows password is later accessed?  If the user forgets the old password are they in trouble?  Or does Windows provide a "migration" path for updating old encrypted data that can be made seamless to the user?

Comment: @Robert;Using "CryptProtectData" Windows will take care of password changes and so on transparently. But 1) If you lose your account password data can't be accessed 2) Data are valid only for that account (or machine if CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE is used). It's not an easy portable format.

Comment: @RobertOschler If you *"change"* your password it will continue to work. If you're a roaming user it will work from other machines. You don't have to worry about an administrator *"resetting"* your password and then being able to get at your stuff ("reset" doesn't work, only "change"). If you password *is* reset behind your back, you can simply change it back and get at your data again. Then you need to choke out the tongue of the person who tried to reset your password without your permission.

Comment: That is really interesting, would mind sharing the rest of the source(API definitions) to make the sample compilable?

Comment: @TobiasR i thought everything else in there was standard Windows API stuff, oops. Added extra functions

Answer (score 2):

Encode your password file with the main password. Don't store that password anywhere; simply query it before decrypting the password file. If someone enters a wrong password, the password file will be scrambled.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I must ask it each time the user modify something in the data to store. It could be tiresome I think !

Comment: hm I don't really understand your use case then. The *users* modify their password... you want the password file to be protected. So where would you want to get the main password into play?

Comment: I use KeePass, and this is the scheme it uses. I run the program, open an encryped database file, it prompts me for my main password, uses it to decrypt the file, then remembers that password until the database is closed. I can edit the database at will, even change the main password. The database file is re-encrypted with the current password whenever it is saved back to file. The password encrypts the database file itself, not the stored user passwords. There is no need to encrypt them individually when the entire file is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

What you could probably do is use a one-way hash for all passwords, without the need for a master password at all.

The nice thing with a hash is that it may be readable by everyone, they aren't any the smarter, since the only way to break a hashed password is a brute-force attack. Which is all the more time consuming that the hash is "large".

Of course, this won't hold if passwords stored are easily discoverable by a dictionary attack, but then is your master password secure?

Comment: I can't use hashes for those password, because the user must be able to read and modify them, so with hash, it's not easy !!!

Comment: You could have mentioned that in the question ;)

Comment: Have to agree with fge here; hashing the password is normally the way to go. Why do people have to be able to see their password, ie what's the user's benefit? There's a reason you normally don't see your password on a site, and the reason is that the safe way to do it leaves to way to retrieve it

Comment: Nicoals78, I'm trying to make a password keeper (as other software on the web) just to learn and to use it ! So I must see my passwords after i entered them the first time to be stored.

Comment: I think, I will not store main password. So the first time, the program starts, request for it and stores its hash in a memory variable (not worrying about methods to discover this, i'm not making a top-secret encrypter). Like this, when a I want to encrypt something, I will only use this hash. What do you think ?

Comment: Why is this the "answer" when asker has stated that this doesn't do what was wanted?

Comment: **Rainbow tables** allow to break hashed passwords in a short time, if the password is not strong enough. Hashes are good to protect password from casual inspection. Don't rely on them for full security. Also if you need the passwords to cipher other files you need a reversible encryption for the stored password. You could crypt with the hash, true, but the hash then is the password and you need to protect it.

Comment: I will never store hash to be sure that no one break it with a rainbow table.

Answer (score 0):

Check out how password safe http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/ solves the problem.

1. Assemble the list-of-passwords-to-be-encrypted.
2. Generate two random 128 bit numbers using a secure random generator. Use the first as HMAC key for later authentication and integrity checks. Use the second as AES-CBC key for encrypting the list-of-passwords-to-be-encrypted. Append the HMAC output to the end of the encrypted list.
3. Generate a third random number. Use this as salt together with the password for deriving a key encryption key using a PBKDF. Use the key encryption key for encrypting the two random keys in step 2.
4. Optionally, generate a password verifier by hashing your password a sufficiently large number of times.

The final file should have the following layout, formatting omitted
 [salt][password verifier][encrypted encryption key][encrypted hmac key][encrypted password list][hmac value]

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in our new SmartUtils Password SDK: http://sutils.com/index.php/smartutils-password-sdk It allows to store passwords with related info like URLs, usernames etc. in AES-256 encrypted database file. A master password may be encrypted using DPAPI in one line of code.